# How excel formula is calculated

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out why my excel code takes so long to update. Suppose that

```
 A->B
```

means that B is dependent on A and I have a dependence structure like below.

```
A -> B -> D
     B -> G
     C -> D
       -> E
       -> F
```

If I change C, it makes sense that D, E and F will be re-evaluated. However, since D also depends on B, I presume that the data from B will be pulled.

My question is: Will excel be pulling just a numeric value from B or will it "re-evaluated" B in it's formulaic form and thus update G and pull data from A?

Comment: That depends on the formulas being used.  Some are volatile and recalculate every time regardless if the data on which it depends changes or not.

Comment: So you're saying that if I have a volatile statement Z which only depends on Y, changing a random cell A will also update cell Z? Most of my data uses If, Lookup, Indirect, Trend or Add in functions.

Comment: Yes it will calculate. See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx

Comment: The issue is the INDIRECT() function.  Unless the INDIRECT is to refer to a dynamic sheet name or is being used in an array formula as a counter, it can usually be replaced with an INDEX formula that is not volatile.

Comment: Will volatile formulas like indirect get updated if I enter data in another worksheet or also workbook (another excel file that is open)? Would you be able to give me a simple example of what you mean by used as a counter? Thanks!!

Comment: I am not sure on the other workbook but other sheets it will still calculate.  As to the counter in array something like this `ROWS(INDIRECT("1:" & B1))`  If you show one of your INDIRECT formulas I can help see it is possible to change to a non volatile function.

Comment: It's typically something like TREND( indirect(cell & row()) : indirect(cell & row),  indirect(cell & row()) : indirect(cell & row), value). cell = an address value like $B$5

Comment: I've been trying to do index(cell&row:cell&row,1) but it wouldn't work

Comment: yeah if you have a sheet full of those it would definitely slow done the calcs.  So you would do something like this `TREND(INDEX(B:B,ROW()):INDEX(B:B,ROW()+1),...)`

Comment: Is there a way to not actually type B but make it refer to another cell using something like lookup? Because they don't necessarily shift by one column (sometimes more columns) as I drag the formula and I have 30k of those :(

Comment: I am sure we can but more information there are three possible criteria in the INDEX(), INDEX(range,row,column)  So set your range for all the columns A:DDD or whatever, then use MATCH() to find the correct column.